# Netlogo: move turtles to non-occupied patches and print it

Tags: netlogo, move

I want to move turtles to one of patches not fully occupied (n-jobs-to-fill != 0). The code is

```
ask turtles [move-to one-of patches with [n-jobs-to-fill != 0]
```

After each allocation turtle-patch, n-jobs-to-fill (that works like a counter) counts one place less

```
ask patches [set n-jobs-to-fill n-jobs-to-fill - 1]
```

Can you help me to do that iteratively (for each tick) and to test it by printing each movement turlte-patch in the observer line?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part where you ask patches to update their variable should not be done with a general `ask patches`, as this will target all patches and either be called too seldom (if you do it just once per iteration of `go`) or too often (if you do it every time a specific patch receives a turtle).

To easily target the specific patch that just received a turtle, and exactly the amount of times that it receives a turtle, make the moving turtle ask its new patch to perform the update. Or even better: given that turtles can directly access the patches-own variables of the patch they are standing on, you can do:

```
patches-own [
  n-jobs-to-fill
]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  
  ask patches [
    set n-jobs-to-fill random 10
  ]
  
  create-turtles 10
end


to go
  if (not any? patches with [n-jobs-to-fill != 0]) [stop]
  
  ask turtles [
    if (any? patches with [n-jobs-to-fill != 0]) [
      move-to one-of patches with [n-jobs-to-fill != 0]
      set n-jobs-to-fill n-jobs-to-fill - 1
      
      show (word "I moved to " patch-here ", which now has " n-jobs-to-fill " jobs to fill")
    ]
  ]
  
  tick
end
```